Non-class type 'MyEnum' cannot conform to class protocol 'PersistentModel'
How do I make the following enumType NotificationType to

conform to class protocol 'PersistentModel'

I'm using this for SwiftData schema. I can do a workaround and make var type: Int or some other type but it will make the code prone to errors and mistakes in long run.
enum NotificationType{
    case promotion, transaction
}

@available(iOS 17, *)
@Model
class NotificationObject {
    var id = UUID()
    ..
    var type: NotificationType
    ..    

    init(id: UUID = UUID(), type: NotificationType) {
        self.id = id
        self.type = type
    }
    
}

What can I try next?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/preserving-your-apps-model-data-across-launches

Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

In SwiftData value types such as enum or struct need to conform to Codable to be correctly saved.
enum NotificationType: Codable {
    case promotion, transaction
}

In SwiftData only classes can be used as model
